# The file you are trying to open (filename).xls is different format VB

Tags: vb.net, excel, export

I am currently trying to open an excel document through my webpage and I keep getting this error:

> "The file you are trying to open "PaymentApplication.xls" is in a
>   different format than specified by the extension"

The excel sheet works fine, but I cant figure out how to get rid of the error.
I have tried numerous things to try and get rid of it and i can't seem to get rid of it

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub excelBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles excelBtn.Click
    Dim sw, sw0 As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    Dim hw0 As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw0)
    Dim frm As HtmlForm = New HtmlForm()
    Dim frm1 As HtmlForm = New HtmlForm()


    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;Filename=PaymentApplication.xls")
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"


    Response.Charset = ""
    EnableViewState = False
    frm.Attributes("runat") = "server"
    Controls.Add(frm)
    frm.Controls.Add(AppPayments)

    'InscapeLogo.RenderControl(hw)

    frm.Controls.Add(GridView1)
    frm.RenderControl(hw)
    Response.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

If i could get some assistance with this it would be much appreciated, Thankyou in Advance

Comment: It looks like you are sending HTML to the browser with an Excel content type and an .xls extension.  Is that about right?  In that case, Excel is correct, the file **is** in a different format.  The only way I know of to get rid of the message is to send the data in .xls format (we had a similar issue sending the old Excel XML data - SpreadsheetML? - to Excel as .xls) and instead switched to XLSX using the [OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), using a wrapper (ClosedXML in my case, but there are others).

Comment: Hi, I've tried using the .xlsx and using the "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", but when I try this I get a new error. "File format or file extension is not valid". I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: You will have to change how you generate the data, not just the content type.  You can't send HTML to Excel and expect it not to complain about the format.

Comment: Ahh sweet, any suggestions as to how I can do that?

Comment: Try [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/) or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).  They are all wrappers around the OpenXML SDK, linked in my first comment, for creating Excel XLSX-format documents.